# What name should I ring?

Tags: grammaticality, questions, syntactic-analysis

I just wanted to ask whether the question in the title sounds "native-like" enough or if there is a better way to say it, especially something less colloquial. The context would be following: I am coming over to somebody elses place and I need to figure out what tag on a panel of doorbells (hope that makes sense) I need to press to ring their bell. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hey Vojtech! Perhaps this question would be received better on https://ell.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Which doorbell should I ring?"

You do not know that there is a name on the bell, there might be a number instead, but 'ring' is ambiguous and might refer to a phone call.